# Is it possible to register some COM component during the azure webjob deploing?

Tags: azure, com, azure-webjobs

Is it possible to register some COM component during the azure webjob deploying?
I know that is possible for worker/web role but i need for webjob.

As result:
I found in the manual mentioned below.

COM Components – Web Apps does not allow the registration of COM Components on the platform. If your websites or applications make use of any COM Components, you must rewrite them in managed code and deploy them with the website or application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webjobs run within the context of a web app. You cannot install a COM component in a web app, so, no... you can't install a COM component within a webjob.

If you need COM, you'll need to use either a Windows VM or a web/worker role.

Answer (score 2):

WebJobs run on Azure App Service, and Azure App Service generally does not support any form of machine global installations. The means you cannot change the registry, nor add system level files. Hence you will not be able to register a COM component.

Some reference to this in the [doc](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-migration-from-iis-server/). Search for 'COM component' in there.